# Who is the first-person narrator in Dan Simmons's "The Hollow Man"?

Tags: telepathy, dan-simmons, the-hollow-man

The scenes in Simmons's *[The Hollow Man](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11277.The_Hollow_Man)* alternate between third person omniscient and first person, with the first person narrator apparently having a fairly omniscient view of Jeremy Bremen's life, speaking of it almost as in retrospect. My suspicion is that the narrator is intended to be Robby, a blind/deaf/autistic child whose tragic story is told in between scenes with Bremen. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollow_Man_(Simmons_novel)) states it as fact, but I'm uncertain of the evidence for it. Is there a Word of God answer on this from the author, or at least some good evidence?